# How to UPDATE a field with a BIT datatype in mysql

Tags: mysql, jstl, bit

I would like to change the availability of an item in a database.

```
<td><select name="avl">
    <option value="1" name="true ">Available</option>
    <option value="0" name="false">Unavailable</option>
    </select>
</td>
```

Here is my sql statement to update the field.

```
<sql:update dataSource="${dbsource}" var="count">
    UPDATE restaurant SET available = ? WHERE idrestaurant ='${param.id}'
    <sql:param value="${param.avl}" />
</sql:update>
```

my datatype for the FIELD available is BIT.

But I get this error.

WARNING:   StandardWrapperValve[jsp]: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Data too long for column 'available' at row 1

Answer (score 0):

I'm using `BIT` in MySQL the same way you are. I understand this is a bit different from your situation but hopefully it will help.

I have a column:

```
NAME:PUBLISHED | DATATYPE:BIT
```

that gets toggled via a button on a page.

```
<li sec:authorize="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')">
   <a th:href="@{'/administration/'+*{postId} + '/publish'}" th:text="*{postMetaData.published} ? 'unpublish' : 'publish'">publish</a>
</li>
```

The controller mapped above is calls the following method in the service:

```
public boolean togglePublishPost(int postId){
    Post post = postRepo.findOne(postId);
    if(post.isPublished()){
        post.setPublished(false);
    }else{
        post.setPublished(true);
        post.setPublishDate(new Date());
    }
    postRepo.save(post);
    return post.isPublished();
}
```

Like I said, it's different but it looks like we are kinda trying to achieve the same thing. So, I guess in short, a `BIT` can be updated with `true` and `false`.